# SandBox Iframe - Blocked script execution in 'URL' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set

Tags: javascript, iframe, sandbox

I am working on a project which requires my clients web sites to be loaded through a 3rd party site. Now this site is loading them through an Iframe with Sandbox"".

Now I understand that this restricts, the java on site and cookies and redirects etc from the hosted site for security.

How ever this site uses Tabs to display content on the page which are being blocked, I understand that it blocks the youtube videos from loading etc, as a third party URL But why is it stopping the Tabs from loading the page content.

Blocked script execution in 'http://manusood.com/Sample-report-Hand' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.

So can't use script to set display:block on tab select?

Is their a way round this problem so they do work in a Sandbox Iframe? Do I need to use html5 tabs instead, not sure this would work ever?

Any ideas?

Thanks
Carl